# Is there a way to use onSchedule and also set a custom 'timeoutSeconds' and 'memory' using Firebase functions V2?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have had to revert back to using Firebase functions V1 in order to schedule the running of my functions and also specify the runtime options including timeoutSeconds and memory in my code (written in TypeScript):

```
const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: "1GB" as const,
};
exports.cleanupEvents = functions
    .runWith(runtimeOpts)
    .pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *")
    .timeZone("Europe/Berlin")
    .onRun(async () => {
        await cleanupOldEvents(adminDb);
        logger.log("Event cleanup finished");
    });
```

Does anyone know if it is possible with Firebase functions V2 using the [onSchedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions?gen=2nd#write_a_scheduled_function) syntax to also specify these runtimeOpts in code? Without needing to go into the google cloud console and manually setting it there.

I have tried chaining'onSchedule' and 'runWith' together and seeing what other possibilities Emmet suggests, so far but had no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [API documentation for onSchedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler.md#scheduleronschedule) suggests that you can pass an object as the first parameter, which is a [ScheduleOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler.scheduleoptions.md#schedulerscheduleoptions_interface) object, an extension of [GlobalOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptions_interface):

```js
onSchedule({
    schedule: "your-schedule-here",
    timeoutSeconds: your-timeout,
    memory: your-memory,
    // include other options here from SchedulerOptions or GlobalOptions
}, (event) => { ... })
```